# Java mail Api fetch message content from MS Exchange server very slow

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have service written using java mail api and spring. Below is code snippet for reading message.

First Store object is created using spring bean as below

```
<bean id="store" factory-bean="imap_session" factory-method="getStore">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="imaps"/>
</bean>

<bean id="imap_session" class="javax.mail.Session">
   <constructor-arg index="0">
    <props>
       <prop key="mail.imap.partialfetch">false</prop>
       <prop key="mail.mime.decodefilename">true</prop>
       <prop key="mail.imap.port">993</prop>
       <prop key="mail.imap.ssl.protocols"></prop>
       <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
      <prop key="mail.imap.ssl.enable">true</prop>
    </props>
 </constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg index="1">
    <null/>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

And java code snippet to connect with server and fetch messages is as below

```
public Message[] getMessages() throws MessagingException, ConfigurationException {
try {
store.connect(host, user, password);
} catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
log.error("AuthenticationFailedException: " + e.getMessage());
}  catch(Exception ex) {
log.error("Exception: in connection with mail server " + ex.getMessage());
  }
Folder inFolder =  store.getFolder(name);
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
int count = inFolder.getMessageCount();
int length = count < numberOfMessagesToFetch ? count : numberOfMessagesToFetch;
Message[] messages = inFolder.getMessages(1, length);
// Commented out below settings 
/*FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.FLAGS);
fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);*/
//fp.add(IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.MESSAGE);
//IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem

/*fp.add("X-mailer");
inFolder.fetch(messages, fp);*/
return messages;
}
```

Below is code snippet which download the attachement

```
try{
  Object content = message.getContent();
  Multipart msgMultipart = (Multipart) content;
  Part part = multipart.getBodyPart(0);
  File attachmentFile = new File("path of file");
  FileOutputStream os = null;
  os = new FileOutputStream(attachmentFile);
  IOUtils.copy(part.getInputStream(), os);
  os.flush();
} finally {
  IOUtils.closeQuietly(os);
}
```

There is some more processing of message like getting some header field values for eg. received time, sender etc.

Problem is that for one server which is not Microsoft Exchange server, above code snippet takes 3-4 sec to download an attachment of size 315k. But another server which exchange server, same code is incredibly slow taken 10+seconds. This is a big bottleneck.

What can be reasons for this slowness. Please help me if any one has a solution.How can make this fast to work with Exchange mail Server.

Comment: Most likely it's network speed. Where are your severs located (physically?) Sometimes logging in can take seconds already.

Comment: @Jan , I agreed with you. But can there be any other reason(s)? . Exchange Server and java mail client, can this be reason for slow response as both use different technologies. I heard that Exchange Server use MAPPI protocol but java does not support it. So can there be such reason like protocol?

Comment: Also other mail clients like Thunderbird fetched emails at very fast speed from the same Exchange Mail Server.

Comment: You fetch all at once - might take lots of memory - have you cecked garbage collector?

Comment: I did an app like that once, and have same slowless. After checking, problem came from the server (postfix+cyrus). Time is spent a lot in connection. But If you launch many clients in parallel, it is the same time. We used this property. I guess mail servers have some strategy of powdering.

Comment: @jan, yes I am fetching a max. of 100 emails. Also they way I am fetching emails, they are not downloaded, but only message references are get. then content is get per message as per request. But same setting is working satisfactory for one mail server. It is working very slow only for Exchange mail server.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina , can you please explain a little bit more, what settings of server should I check?

Comment: we never found parameters to change that. I guess it is hard-coded. It is not extraordinary that Exchange is not very good with his non-natural protocol. it is here for compatibiliy, MS advise to use MS products :) . Good luck !

Comment: It looks like you're using the "imaps" protocol, but setting properties for the "imap" protocol.  That means the property settings are being ignored.  Since you're setting "mail.imap.ssl.enable", you can just use the "imap" protocol, and you can get rid of the socket factory property.  That should allow the partialfetch property to apply, which will cause the attachments to be downloaded in one operation.

Comment: @BillShannon, Thanks for your reply. In-fact I was expecting something from you. I need to run this service on secure connection using "imaps" protocole. Should I use property setting like this <prop key="mail.imaps.partialfetch">false</prop> i.e. using "imaps" instead of "imap". And also, can you please let me know which properties should I set and which should I remove from the above mentioned setting.

Comment: @BillShannon , by changing imap to imaps in property setting like this <prop key="mail.imaps.partialfetch">false</prop> for all above mentioned properties, I started getting "handshake_failure" exception. Please let me know the correct way of using "imaps" protocol for secure connection on port 993, so that service can give it's best response.

Comment: Using the "imaps" protocol is the same as setting the "mail.imap.ssl.enable" property and using the "imap" protocol; they both use IMAP over SSL.  The property names just have to match the protocol name that you use.

Comment: Thanks @BillShannon for your valuable help. It works for me. And handshake_failure exception was coming because I was not setting the property "mail.imap.ssl.protocols". After setting it to TLSv2, it works fine. Just last comment from you, should I use "FetchProfile". As in my code snippet, should I un-comment the commented portion. Does using "FetchProfile" increase the speed, as I am getting various information from message like header, sender, receiver etc.

Comment: Using Folder.fetch causes it to fetch all the requested information in one operation, storing it locally so that you can access it later.  That means one large operation with lots of data instead of many operations with a small amount of data.  Whether that improves the performance of your application depends on how your applications uses the data, but in general it can be a significant improvement.

Comment: Thanks @BillShannon for your help